# php array implode

Tags: php, arrays, implode

I have this array:

```
array (size=5)
  35 => string '3' (length=1)
  24 => string '6' (length=1)
  72 => string '1' (length=1)
  16 => string '5' (length=1)
  81 => string '2' (length=1)
```

I want to implode id to get:

```
$str = '35-3|24-6|72-1|16-5|81-2';
```

How to get it the easy way?

Thanks.

Comment: When you say `How to get it the easy way?` you mean without loop right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but it should be pretty straight forward ...

```
foreach($array as $key=>$item){
    $new_arr[] = $key."-".$item;
}

$str = implode('|', $new_arr);
```

Answer (score 5):

One possibility would be like this

```
function mapKeyVal($k, $v) {
    return $k . '-' . $v;
}

echo implode('|', array_map('mapKeyVal', 
                            array_keys($arry), 
                            array_values($arry)
                           )
      );
```

Comment: +1 Don't forget that you can implement an anonymous function ! http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: yes, I thought it would make it a bit "more understandable" :-)

Comment: Anonymous `function($l, $r) { return "$l-$r"; }`.

Comment: Thanks @Gremo, as I said above, considering the question, wanted to make the answer not "too complicated" :-)

Comment: @Havelock: This solution works, and while callback can be anonymous function, there are many hosts out there supporting PHP older than 5.3 (so without anynymous functions). See my answer for more general alternative.

Answer (score 4):

You <s>cannot</s> can do this using implode, see @havelock's answer below, however it would be easier to use a loop or another form of iteration.

```
$str = "";

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

    $str .= $key . "-" . $value . "|";

}

$str = substr(0, strlen($str)-1);
```

Comment: You can use rtrim() as well to remove last "|"

Comment: I would insist you can do that with `implode()` as part of the solution as well... see my answer :-)

Comment: He can have a scroll of the page if he wants to see the other options, I don't need to list them in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

You can do it cleanly by joining strings, while using eg. custom associative mapping function, which looks like that:

```php
function array_map_associative($callback, $array){
    $result = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value){
        $result[] = call_user_func($callback, $key, $value);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

### Full example and test

The full solution using it could look like that:

```php
<?php

function array_map_associative($callback, $array){
    $result = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value){
        $result[] = call_user_func($callback, $key, $value);
    }
    return $result;
}

function callback($key, $value){
    return $key . '-' . $value;
}

$data = array(
    35 => '3',
    24 => '6',
    72 => '1',
    16 => '5',
    81 => '2',
);

$result = implode('|', array_map_associative('callback', $data));

var_dump($result);
```

and the result is:

```
string(24) "35-3|24-6|72-1|16-5|81-2"
```

which matches what you expected.

The proof is here: http://ideone.com/HPsVO6